# Does NodeJs needs public file permissons to access file?

Tags: node.js, file-permissions

I tried accessing data with FileZilla and additionally downloading it. This worked. However, now I tried accessing the same file with the same user with nodeJS with "GET". Here I get the Error "Access Denied".

I looked into the permissions, and the owner and group of the file are able to read and write the file, but no public permissions. My user is part of the "Group". However, I am now wondering, if the file needs to have public permissions to read and write in order to access the file via nodeJs?

Quick Info: I access the file both with FileZilla and NodeJS via SFTP. All configs / user etc. are the same.

Code:

```
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();

sftp.connect({
    host: config.development.host,
    port: config.development.port,
    username: config.development.username,
    password: config.development.password
}).then(() => {
    return sftp.get(`${config.development.pathToFile}/${filename}`);
}).then(async (data) => {
    console.log('data', data);
    csv({
            noheader: true,
            output: "csv"
        })
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you post the server code that handles the GET request ?

Comment: @EMX Yes sorry! If that helps

Comment: very strange, cant seem to replicate your issue. sorry

Comment: @EMX but the file on my server does not need to have public file permissions in order to access it with sftp nodejs GET?

Comment: The strange fact is that as you mention, the same credentials yield different results. If you are able of downloading it with any other SFTP client, then there must be an errata in your code somewhere?

Comment: @EMX so I first used my other server with the same code (other user and server). Here everything works with FileZilla AND Nodejs. Switching to this server, I get the problem, that I can only access the files with FileZilla. The files here have owners & group permissions. I am not the owner of the file, and I am not 100% sure if I am in the group. BUT I can download and access the files with File Zilla. So I don't know if its the code or maybe the server? I wouldnt be able to access the files in either way if I dont have permissons right? (e.g. not in the group)

Comment: I would try a different module like "ssh2", good luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195120/discussion-between-threxx-and-emx).

Comment: You managed to find the solution to the permissions issue ?

Comment: @EMX actually no. I switched to ssh2 and had the same problem, but when I use fastGet / fastPut it works without errors. So I just split my function, one where I get the files, and then an extra script for converting the files.

Answer (score 0):

> Does NodeJs needs public file permissons to **access** file?

As long as the user that spawned the `Node.js` process has read permissions for the specific file, you shouldn't encounter any problems.

---

I would suggest learning how multi-user environments & permissions management works.

## Recommended reading :

- [Learning the shell - Lesson 9: Permissions](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php)
- [Linux Tutorial - 8. Understand Permissions](https://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/permissions.php)

## Recommended further reading :

> The default Linux security model is a bit inflexible. To give special
> access (such as modification privileges) to a group of people, you
> have to get your system administrator to create a group with those
> people in it. Furthermore, if you would like to give a different set
> of access privileges (such as read access) to another group of people,
> you can’t do it because you can only assign one group owner per file
> or directory. To solve this problem, you can use ACLs (Access Control
> Lists). You can learn more about them from this link: [ACLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)

*[(Quote extracted from here)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permissions-in-linux/)*

After all, it will come in handy and it wont take you much effort to understand.